# Pandas String to Integer by Character

Tags: python, string, pandas, integer, apply

In a Pandas data frame column, I want to convert each character in a string to an integer (as is done with ord()) and add 100 to the left. I know how to do this with a regular string:

```
st = "JOHNSMITH4817001141979"
a=[ord(x) for x in st]
b=[]
for x in a:
    b.append('{:03}'.format(x)) #Add leading zero, ensuring 3 digits
b=['100']+b
b=''.join([ "%s"%x for x in b])
b=int(b)
b
```

Result: `100074079072078083077073084072052056049055048048049049052049057055057`

But what if I wanted to perform this operation on every cell of a column in a Pandas data frame like this one?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'string':['JOHNSMITH4817001141979','JOHNSMYTHE4817001141979']})
df

    string
0   JOHNSMITH4817001141979
1   JOHNSMYTHE4817001141979
```

I just need a separate column with the result as an integer for each cell in 'string'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you transform your processing chain into a function such as:

```
def get_it(a):
    a=[ord(x) for x in st]
    b=[]
    for x in a:
        b.append('{:03}'.format(x)) #Add leading zero, ensuring 3 digits
    b=['100']+b
    b=''.join([ "%s"%x for x in b])
    return int(b)
```

and then you call it iteratively for each element in the column and make this list the new column

```
df['result'] = [get_it(i) for i in df['string']]
```

Although this does work, I yet think that you can find a better solution by optimizing your process "get_it"

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can do the following:

```
def get_it(a):
a=[ord(x) for x in st]
b=[]
for x in a:
    b.append('{:03}'.format(x)) #Add leading zero, ensuring 3 digits
b=['100']+b
b=''.join([ "%s"%x for x in b])
return int(b)
df['result'] = df['string'].apply(get_it)
```

Comment: Hello, to help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner(Python 3.6+)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'string':['JOHNSMITH4817001141979','JOHNSMYTHE4817001141979']})

df['string'].apply(lambda x:''.join(['100']+[f'{ord(i):03}' for i in x])).astype(int)
```

For Python < 3.6, replace f-format to '{ord(i):03}'.format(i=i). What I have done is transform your function into a lambda expression and apply it to the column.